# AngularJS directive not being called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to implement a d3 directive in Angular, and it's hard because visually nothing is happening, and no errors are being thrown on the console.

Here's my d3 directive:

```
myApp.directive('d3-bars', ['d3Service', function($window, d3Service) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

// More code below ....
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<d3-bars bar-height="20" bar-padding="5"></d3-bars>
```

At first I thought it wasn't appending an `svg`, because inspecting the element that's what it looks like, but now I don't think the directive is even running at all.  I stuck a `console.log` inside of it at the very beginning and it didn't appear either.  Am I missing something simple?

**EDIT:**

I tried changing the top line to

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', ['d3'])
.directive('d3-bars', ['d3Service', function($window, d3Service) {
```

But that didn't work either.  I don't even know what's the difference between the two headers anyway...

Comment: Is this giving you an error, because I would expect an error if you're only injecting  'd3Service' in the array of dependency injection as opposed to inject both ['$window', 'd3Service', function($window, d3Service) {//code etc}]

Comment: ^^  Perfect.  Your answer plus Engima's worked great.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your directive name may be wrong. Angular directives are commonly camel-cased. And when in the HTML they are hypenated. so `ngClass` turns into `ng-class` in the HTML.

At least when I've tried to use `-` or other characters in my directives it hasn't worked.

Check out this Google Group post for some validity: [using dash in directive](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/KqNnzmCwi5M)

Also here are the docs: [Directives - matching directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#matching-directives)

You'll also want to make the change that was suggested in the comments by JoshSGman:

```
.directive('d3Bars',['$window', 'd3Service', function($window, d3Service) {
```

Comment: Ohh... now I get "Cannot read property 'd3' of undefined at link".  An error... woo hoo!

Comment: You will probably also need to make the change that @JoshSGman suggested as well.

Comment: If you edit your answer to attribute @JoshSGman's comment, I'll select this as the correct answer.

Comment: This helped me immediately, I was fighting with this problem for an hour before realizing there was something fundamentally wrong with the way I implemented my directive, compared to a Plunkr example I was referencing.  Thanks.

Comment: I was really wondering why it didn't work. So, I stripped down my directive to a bare minimum but still had no luck. Then I found your answer! :) Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: My problem was that **I was using underscore `_` in the directive name, which didn't work**

Comment: While I was struggling with harder dependency problems I was missing the obvious: a hyphen character in my directive name :(

Answer (score 10):

the naming of your directive is the problem. Angular normalizes the names of directives in the html before it matches them to the names in JavaScript. The normalization process works in two steps:

1. Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.
2. Convert the colon-, hyphen-, or underscore-delimited name to camelCase.

So, the correct name for your directive in JavaScript would be `d3Bars`. Change it to that and it should work.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#matching-directives for more information.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing happened to me that made the directive not to work at all

when you have `one module` have a directive and `you created a new module` with a new directive but due to the copy-paste `you forget change Module name`, this way `AngulerJs` somehow `will` `remove the first directive`

so

> make sure that every module have unique name

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar behavior when I forgot to define the `link` property.

No errors in the console, nothin.